# Analysis, supB < supA proof question.

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty bounded above subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\text{sup}B < \text{sup}A$. (1)

(a) Prove that there exists a real number $a$ such that $a \in A$ and $a$ is an upper bound of $B$.

(b) Is the result still true if we replace hypothesis (1) with the weaker hypothesis $\text{sup}B \leq \text{sup}A$?

(a) So I know that, you need the approximation property for suprema to show that there is an element in $A$ which is greater than $\text{sup}B$ but less than $\text{sup}A$. But I am unsure how to apply this and therefore hence prove the first statement.

Comment: (i) If $a > \sup B$ then it is an upper bound for $B$. (ii) You cannot show that there is an element less than $\sup A$. $A$ could be a singleton.

Comment: "you need the approximation property for suprema"  What is the approximation property for suprema.   "but less than supA" It doesn't have to be less than $\sup A$.  After all if $A = (0,5)\cup \{7\}$ and $B =(0,6)$ then $\sup A = 7$ but $a < \sup A; a\in A$ means that $a < 5 < 6=\sup B$.

Comment: You should be able to prove that if $y < \sup A$ then there is an $a \in A$ so that $y < a$.  That's almost (but just one step removed) the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the definitions.

$\sup A$ is the least upper bound of $A$.  What does that *mean*?  What is the definition.

Def: 1) $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A$.  And if $y < \sup A$ then $y$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$.

Well, $\sup B < \sup A$ so $\sup B$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$.

Well what does *that* mean?

If $y$ is an upper bound of $A$ means $y \ge a$ for all $a \in A$.  SO if $y$ is *not* an upper bound of $A$ that means that there is an $a \in A$ so that $y < a$.

So $\sup B$ is not an upper bound of $A$ so there is an $a \in A$ so that $\sup B < a$.

Now what can we say about $a$ in terms of the elements of $B$?

....

As for b)

If $\sup B = \sup A$ and $a\in A$ is an upper bound of $B$ that would mean $a \ge \sup B$ because $B$ is the *least* upper bound.

But $a \in A$ so $a \le \sup A$ because $\sup A$ is an upper bound of $a$.

So we have $\sup B \le a \le \sup A = \sup B$ so $a =\sup B = \sup A$.

Does that have to happen?  Is $\sup A \in A$ always?